# How can I get an array of shortcodes used in my input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, shortcode

I have a plugin which I am creating for wordpress for the backend. in one section, the user is able to enter text into a textbox. I would like to update a list at the top of the screen with all the shortcodes they have entered every time they lift a key, as well as their values.

to this end, I have written the following code for testing purposes:

```
$("#BBPlugin-Pages").on("keyup",".BBtextArea",function(e){

    var match = wp.shortcode.next("code", _2upstring, 2);
        if ( ! match ) {
            return;
        }

        else console.log(match.content);
});
```

so now, if I type in [code]words[/code] , it will return that when I type anything, however, if I add another shortcode later in the textbox that reads [code]word2[/code] , it will not be returned as well, only the first shortcode gets returned. is there a way to return both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look [here](https://lkwdwrd.com/wp-shortcode-wp-html-wordpress-shortcodes-javascript/).

wp.shortcode.next( tag, text, index )

Return
Type: Object
A container object with a few helpful properties:

**index: The index where the match occurred so you can easily match the next shortcode using the matched index plus 1.**

```
var index = 2; // yours initial value - don't know why 2
$("#BBPlugin-Pages").on("keyup",".BBtextArea",function(e){

var match = wp.shortcode.next("code", _2upstring, index);
    if ( ! match ) {
        return;
    }

    else {
        index = match.index + 1;
        console.log(match.content);
    }

})
```

Can't test it - but the idea is to save index of current match. And start new search from the next char.

P.S. If someone could test this - write correct code sample if smth is wrong.

upd: log them all. (should work, but can't test w/o environment - you should just pay attention on the idea)

```
    var index = 2; // yours initial value - don't know why 2
    var all = []; 
$("#BBPlugin-Pages").on("keyup",".BBtextArea",function(e){

var match = wp.shortcode.next("code", _2upstring, index);
    if ( ! match ) {
        return;
    } else {
        index = match.index + 1;
        all.push( match.content );
        console.log(all); // as array
        all.forEach(function(x){ console.log(x); }); // one at a time
    }

})
```

Comment: I ran it, though it only displays the last match in the textbox. I was hoping maybe it could log them all